# Android: Recycler View item icon with colour filter issue on lollipop

Tags: android

**Background**

I am making a navigation drawer where the icons utilise colour filtering to change the colour of the icon without needing a new asset.

So when the item is clicked, the icon changes colour to the colour that was set in addition to the text title.

**The problem**

On pre-lollipop devices, it works. I click and hold an item and the colour of both changes correctly. Great!. But on lollipop, this is not the case. Only the text changes colour and not the icon.

**My code**

I am showing relevant code to keep things light. Please let me know if more is needed

This is my selector located in res/color

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/emerald"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/emerald"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/emerald"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

This is where i set the colour filter which is a method inside a RecyclerView.ViewHolder and called in onBindViewHolder

```
public void setIcon(int iconResourceId){
            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,iconResourceId);
            drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable.mutate(),mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.navigation_drawer_item_selector));
            mItemIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }
```

**What is weird**

If i force selection like so (passing in true), it works, both items are coloured so the colour filtering is working but not when i click and hold.

```
 public void setSelected(boolean isSelected){
            mItemIcon.setSelected(isSelected);
            mItemName.setSelected(isSelected);
        }
```

If any more info is needed let me know

Comment: Bump. Any ideas?, been investigating for a few days, cant find whats wrong :(

Comment: Well even calling setTintList (the API 21 method) still has the same issue. So it must be something else.

Comment: have you solve this? I also have this problem in my code.

Comment: @01.sunlit, I have not,  unfortunately :(